# Problem connecting my AVD to android studio or cmd

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to download flutter with android studio to make my first app but I am encountering some problems. I am following the Academind tutorial on YT, but now I cant connect to my Emulator in the AVD manager

In the future i want to have VScode as my editor but yo still have to make a connection with the emulator via android studio first, right?

When trying to run my pixel 2 AVD it says "unable to locate adb". The emulator is then launched, but not connected to android studio. When trying to do "flutter run" the command prompt it says "No supported devices connected."

Under C: program files/Android i only find an android studio folder. No Build tools, emulator or extras, like the tutorial guy has. Is this a problem? I have tried to reinstall android studio but it did not do anything.